# Outputting date using debug in dosbox

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, dosbox

I have a script I wrote to output the date in assembly using dos interrupts.

```
N date.txt
N
N This script will generate date.com
N
N date.com
A 100
   db '0000/00/00 0$'
   mov ah,2a
   int 21
   mov bx,100
   mov [bx],cx
   mov [bx+5],dh
   mov [bx+8],dl
   mov [bx+11],al
   mov dx,bx
   mov ah,9
   int 21
   int 20

RCX
027
W
Q
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this but it appears to only output garbage. My first guess is that the addressing is wrong and I shouldn't be referencing 100, but that is where the application and my string buffer is being stored.

Sample Output:
[image]

Comment: Put your data after the code not before it. Either that or you'll have to insert a JMP instruction at 0100 so that it jumps to the first instruction after the data. The processor in your code will start executing the code as data which is not what you want.

Comment: If using DOSBox you might want to consider using turbo assembler (TASM).

Comment: You will also have to convert numbers returned by DOS get system date into their string/character equivalents before writing them into the buffer (at the address in BX in your case) that the DOS write string function will output.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I'm using NASM with dosbox (I mean I'm editing the source in Kate (KDE5 text editor), compiling with NASM in my 64b linux, and then I run dosbox with the final COM file, so I'm using mostly the current and updated tools, except the validation itself (and for debugging I have turbo debugger from my old installation of TASM, running inside dosbox surprisingly well).

Comment: As already pointed out, you'll need to convert values and to that end, unless there is a specific reason for using INT 21H, BIOS service 1A returns BCD values that are a lot easier to convert. I noticed too that assembling with DOSBOX as you have the results aren't correct for either 2A or 2C, but are in EMU8080 on my Win7 machine.

Comment: @Shift_Left I reread your comment and noticed I missed a comma after INT 21h. Oops.Removed my query